# how to view the functions and contents of a library

Tags: c

I want to know how can I see the functions and the contents of a library in C language?

Comment: C and C++ are two *very* different languages. Please don't tag multiple languages if you only ask about one specific language.

Comment: And please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The answer to this question depends on the platform that you are using. Therefore, please specify which operating system your question applies to, or the type of the library file. Or does your question apply to the C standard library? Are you looking for a list of all functions in the C standard library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you cannot see the  source code of functions of a library (e.g. some `libfoo.a` or `libfoo.so.*`  Linux files) compiled from C source code.

You should ask for the documentation of that library. If it is developed in house, you may need to discuss with colleagues.

I do like [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) libraries like [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/). Because you are allowed to download their source code and study it.

Be aware of code obfuscation techniques and of [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem). Decompilation of binary libraries is legally forbidden in some countries.

But a lot of libraries are not open source.

On Linux, tools like [objdump(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) or [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) could be helpful.

Notice that some libraries (e.g. [GNU lightning](https://www.gnu.org/software/lightning/)) are generating new functions and machine code at runtime. Hence the notion of function might be not as easy as you think.

On Linux, programs like [my `manydl.c`](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/)  or [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/), or [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org//), or [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/), are generating code at runtime: for  `manydl.c` and *Bismon*  it generates C code and [dlopen(3)](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/) it after having compiled it as a plugin.

Jacques Pitrat's book *Artificial Beings: the conscience of a conscious machine* ISBN 978-1-84821-101-8  explains the interest of generating code at runtime. A relevant concept is [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

is  `nm libconfig.a | c++filt` what you are looking for?